# How to invoke LivePagedListProvider with argument in room database

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

interface SongDao {

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM song group by artist")
fun getAll(): LivePagedListProvider<Int, Song>

@Query("SELECT * FROM song where album like :arg0")
fun getAllSong(albumName: String): LivePagedListProvider<Int, Song>

@Query("SELECT * FROM song group by album")
fun getAllAlbum(): LivePagedListProvider<Int, Song>
```

}

class SongViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

```
private val doa = AppDatabase.get(app).songDao()

companion object {

    private const val PAGE_SIZE = 30

    private const val ENABLE_PLACEHOLDERS = true
}

val allSong = doa.getAllSong("1989 taylor swift").
        create(0, PagedList.Config.Builder().
                setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE).
                setEnablePlaceholders(ENABLE_PLACEHOLDERS).
                build())
```

}

I want to call getAllSong function, In my AndroidViewModel

i want to replace "1989 taylor swift" with the actual argument that is passed, and how it is passed to it

Comment: and what do you have problems with? whats your calling code? how do you create `LivePagedListBuilder`?

Comment: Question has been updated, Please review it

Comment: you mean `"Jawaan"`? you want to replace it with something else? if so, whats the problem then? (edit your code correctly since it is hard to read it)

Comment: viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SongViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel!!.allSong.observe(this, Observer(adapter::setList))
  I can't pass argument to doa.getAllSong function in my viewmodel

Comment: this is my method for filtering -as-you-type: `public LiveData<PagedList<User>> filter(String s) {
        return new LivePagedListBuilder(dao.filter("%" + s + "%"), 10).build();
    }`

Comment: and in `TextWatcher.afterTextChanged(Editable s)` you call it like this `viewModel.filter(s.toString()).observe(this, this::setList);`

Comment: Thanks , now its working

Comment: good, and for future do not use `LivePagedListProvider` - its deprecated